# Рейтинг игроков через google play plugin - Unity3d

Tags: android, unity3d, google-play

Здравствуйте, при добавлении рейтинга в игру, столкнулся с проблемой, которая вроде и подгружает google play после чего не открывает таблицу рейтинга. Вот что выдает logcat:
 E/TokenRequestor: You have wrong OAuth2 related configurations, please check. Detailed error: UNREGISTERED_ON_API_CONSOLE.

Добавлял все как по документации гугл сервисов, но все равно наткнулся на эту проблему. В консоли все создано правильно и приложение привязано к гугл сервисам.
Если у кого была такая проблема, как можно ее решить?
Версия Unity 5.6.4p2

Answer (score 0):

Эта ошибка - несоответствие сертификатов приложения и сертификата, которым вы подписываете сборку. Вероятнее всего, ваше приложение вообще не подписано.

Вот [вам тема на сайте Unity](https://forum.unity.com/threads/android-signing.62137/) с ответом от официального представителя компании.
Если к сути, то алгоритм следующий:

1) Зайдите в Publishing Settings в PlayerSettings
2) Выберете "Create a new keystore", а затем нажмите "Browse Keystore". Введите название и сохраните файл, следом впишите пароль в поля password и confirm the password
3) В выпадающем списке Key -> Alias выберете "Create a new key"
4) В новом, открывшемся окне введите необходимую информацию.
5) Выберете созданный ключ.
6) Соберите ваше приложение. Теперь оно подписано.

Важно помнить, что Unity не запоминает пароль от вашего Keystore, поэтому его придётся помнить самостоятельно

Если не ошибаюсь, этот же сертификат теперь нужно загрузить на странице разработчика.

[Видеоролик с описанными выше действиями](https://youtu.be/iBmgCnJ_z1k)

Comment: Не помогли данные действия, может есть еще какое-то решение?

Comment: @Nikita, тогда ещё один вариант - несовпадение имён пакетов. Т.е. имя пакета, который загружен на страницу приложения в google play console не совпадает с именем пакета в игре. А т.к. именно по этому id пакета приложение со страницей и связывается - сервисы могут не подключаться

Comment: @Nikita, ещё на форумах Unity присутствует такое решение, связанное с доп.настройкой ключей Google Play https://forum.unity.com/threads/google-play-services-not-working.485322/

Comment: @Nikita, на хабре появилась статья с пошаговым описанием процесса https://habrahabr.ru/post/350458/